# writing a maven plugin that depends on javadocs

Tags: java, maven

my maven plugin project depends on the javadocs of a `dependency` (I parse the javadocs in a `generate-sources` goal).

1. how do I depend on the javadocs
2. how do I get a reference to the `File`?

This is for an OSS project, current attempt to do this is [GenerateJava.java](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/blob/e582b864812f0d777650609a37acfcdf13ee1712/generator/src/main/java/org/netlib/GenerateJava.java).

Comment: you can have a dependency like     `<dependency>
      <groupId>test</groupId>
      <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
    </dependency>`, but I'm not sure if that's what you're asking for...

Comment: That potentially solves part 1, but I still need to get a reference to the actual `File` from my plugin.

Comment: FYI, I need `requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE` in my `@Mojo` and then I can access the artefacts from the `Project` (which needs to be autowired). I am still not 100% sure how to get the javadoc classifier from there.

Comment: @eis I got this to work with your advice. I was looking for a `getClassifier("javadoc")` method on the artifact, but it's a completely separate artifact! Can you please answer the question and I'll mark it as the right answer.

Comment: answered now (and here are some extra characters to fill 15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a partial answer, to have a javadoc dependency you'd specify javadoc as a classifier in pom

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
</dependency>
```